# Data returned by server is different when ran manually and ran in vugen

Tags: loadrunner

I am having a different kind of problem. I have recorded a script using HP Loadrunner Vugen 11.52. When I do the transaction manually, I am getting the list of applications populated properly. But when I ran the same transaction manually, it is not showing any list there.

Please help me out in resolving this issue. I have searched a lot of forums but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Record twice with a clean browser instance and very carefully compare the requests submitted.   It is highly likely that you have missed a piece of dynamic data which needs to be addressed in your code.

Comment: I have tried that but there is no difference in both the scripts.

Comment: Look at the logs, not the run time browser, for validation of information being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried recording the trnsaction both manually and scripted using a tool like fiddler http://fiddler2.com, and compare the calls?

It sounds like there is a correlation error in the script that means the end process isn't completing correctly.

All LoadRunner scripts need to have full correlation, and a check after each call that your script is at the correct place in the process. Checks for onscreen errors are also 'best practice'.